# Before_create not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following model setup. But from what I can tell in the logs, the variable is being saved in the db as null:

```
class Bracket < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :set_round_to_one

  def set_round_to_one
    @round = 1
  end
end
```

I create it by using something like this:

```
bracket = Bracket.new(:name => 'Winners', :tournament_id => self.id)
bracket.save
```

I did use create as supposed to new and save, but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Presuming that `round` is a field in your `brackets` table, you need to call the setter:

`self.round = 1`

That's because `round` is actually a key into the `bracket`'s `attributes` Hash and by calling the setter the value in that Hash is set correctly.

Further, with `@round = 1`, you're simply causing a new instance variable called `round` to be created the first time it is called. And since ActiveRecord does not look for values in instance variables (it looks in the `attributes` Hash), nothing happens as far as saving the value of `@round` is concerned.

Comment: I was just doing `round = 1` and I had the same problem. Prepending `self.` before `round = 1` (e.g. `self.round = 1`) fixed the problem for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It should be

```
class Bracket < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_create :set_round_to_one

    def set_round_to_one
        self.round = 1
    end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Both Zabba and vinceh's solutions are correct, but instead of a before create, I would suggest that you set a default value in your database for the `round` attribute of `Bracket`.

Comment: I agree. It's much much more idiomatic to do it that way.